# Repeat HTML Headers when CSS3 Columns overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to find a way to have my HTML headers to repeat my HTML Headers when my CSS3 Column overflows.

Say I have 3 columns, on the top of them it says "Heading" when the column text goes to a new column the header will also move.

HTML:

```
<div>
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div p {
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ap9stajy/2/

Answer (score 1):

try to count words like this

```
var words =$('.col').text().split(' ');

    var center=($('#wrap').width()/3)+25;
    var right=Number((center+center)+45);
if( words.length <=4){

}
if(words.length >= 4  ){

    $('#h2').attr('style','margin-left:'+center+'px')
}
```

you put the margin if words are > of 4

html

```
<div id="wrap" >
    <h2 id="h2">Heading</h2>
<p class="col">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a 
</p>
</div>
```

css

```
.col {
    columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    -moz-columns: 3;

}
```